# What are the best practices for Angular project code-building with Git?

Tags: angular, gradle

I'm working on a complex Angular framework which contains multiple modules, lazy loading etc. This framework will be placed in `resources` folder of the project with Java as backend. The project will be built by Gradle build. Placing the Angular framework in `resources` folder hangs the system as the Angular framework size will be more than **250 MB**. Excluding `node_modules`, it would be between 5 MB and 10 MB. So, I'm placing the Angular framework outside the project using external Rest APIs to work, for time being. Now, I have to share the code in Git, whose repo is with project alone in which the Angular framework with `node_modules` couldn't be placed due to size constraints.

In one of the solutions, I can place the Angular framework in `resources` folder without `node_modules` and do Git commits, which would become manual procedure, that I have to complete my work outside the `resources` folder *always*, and once done have to *copy-paste* in `resources` folder without `node_modules` for Git committing, which may not be recommended.

Please suggest the best practices for this scenario, so that I can always keep my Angular framework in `resources` folder and continue work, and do Git commit the code from there.

Comment: Did you remove `.gitignore` from angular folder?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. node_modules is not supposed to be versioned in git. It's generated from your package.json file and your lock file alone (which should be versioned). 250 MB of sources is huge, too, unless you're dealing with an awful lot of images. Anyway, the gradle build should automate the packaging: there is no reason to store the Angular source files in your backend source files. Here's an example of a Spring Boot (Java) backend + Angular frontend where gradle assembles everything: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/globe42

Comment: The `node_modules` folder is by default in `.gitignore` so it is excluded from the project by git.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, I'm not sure if you get my concern. I have git repo in which my Java project is cloned. If I place my Angular framework with `node_modules` in that project, the Gradle actions such as Gradle refresh, Gradle clean build, etc., will hung due to size constraints. I'm in the need of best practice(s), with which I can place the Angular framework in the current project alone, with excluded `node_modules` and link it from outside, so that Gradle will not be effected. And I can do Git routines such commit normally, with no `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

By default a Git Ignore file is generated with the project, it already includes node_modules, so you don't have to do anything extra to prevent this heaver folder from being uploaded to git.

.gitignore

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules
```